# Pdf restrictions

Tags: pdf

I have to sent a pdf file to a company and it should not possess restrictions of any type. However, I could not remove the "Changing the document" restriction. Could you help me or indicate how I should proceed?

Comment: It sounds like you trying to circumvent copying restrictions on commercial ebook. If that is not the case, please provide information on how you generated the PDF file?

Comment: It was generated using a tex file.

Comment: If this is a Tex workflow this would probably be better on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to be about ebooks but about generic PDF editing.

Comment: Generic PDF editing is still  in scope for this SE